# tips for dealing with metal studs?

Tags: studs, metal

I'm working on setting up a small little basement shop in our rented townhouse. The basement was finished with metal studs and they've been an absolute pita to accurately locate.

I built a work bench I designed and anchored it to the wall using togglers. I used my stud finder and noticed I was getting 3.5 between readings. I assumed the studs were mounted 90 degrees to the way they should be, 3 of the 4 half inch holes went in well as did the toggles, but the 4th drilled dead center ended up catching an edge and I was unable to use it.. So my guess is the studs were doubled up there? So I moved forward and figured I'd move over an inch still within the stud finder marks annnd just drilled through dry wall.

Ill say that the construction is super shoddy and from floor to ceiling my stud finder indicated studs on angles, random distances from each other etc.

I'm planning to mount a 68x10x10 box shelf above the bench and want to ensure I get the studs for this, but I'm really second guessing here due to my (lack of) experience.

I wish they'd just used wood.. Sorry for the novel, much appreciated to anyone who reads this and has advice.

Comment: How heavy is the box shelf and contents going to be? If the studs aren't anchored well, that might end badly. Safer approach would be to set a cabinet on top of the bench with tall ends.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. You'll note that this is a _QUESTION_ and answer site. I'm having a hard time identifying an actual, objective question here that we could possibly answer for you, just a rambling rant about something, something, something, rental, metal studs. If you have a _specific_ question you'd like us to answer, please [edit] to explicitly state that. A general "tips please" question is far too broad for us to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Take the smallest drill bit that you own, and test for the studs with a sequence of tiny pinholes at 1" spacing. Once you find something, find the edges (and therefore the center) with a tighter pinhole spacing.